# CRUD - Create select dropdown list autofills another input box ASP.NET Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm trying to create something like a combo box in excel. Selecting the Site will automatically select the JobNum and Manager. Site, JobNum, and Manager are from a separate table called master. Currently in the create form that I am trying to do, they are all dropdown list that pulls from the db master table.

Edit - Forgot to mention master table has a simple ID, just an incremental from 1. Added an image for how it looks from the DB

[This is how it currently looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4COYs.png)

[Master table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrAeV.png)

[How I want it to be - selecting site, autofills the bottom two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjZLF.png)

[Master Table from DB showing all columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9xdF.png)

Code for select list:

```
        public SelectList PYSiteSL { get; set; }
        public SelectList PYManagerSL { get; set; }
        public SelectList PYJobNumSL { get; set; }

        public void PopulateSiteDropDownList(FinanceAppARContext _context, object selectedSiteList = null)
        {
            var siteQuery = from s in _context.master
                            select s.Site;
            PYSiteSL = new SelectList(siteQuery.Distinct().AsNoTracking(), selectedSiteList);
        }
        public void PopulateManagerDropDownList(FinanceAppARContext _context, object selectedManagerList = null)
        {
            var managerQuery = from m in _context.master
                               select m.Manager;
            PYManagerSL = new SelectList(managerQuery.Distinct().AsNoTracking(), selectedManagerList);
        }

        public void PopulateJobNumDropDownList(FinanceAppARContext _context, object selectedJobNumList = null)
        {
            var jobnumQuery = from j in _context.master
                              select j.JobNum;
            PYJobNumSL = new SelectList(jobnumQuery.Distinct().AsNoTracking(), selectedJobNumList);
        }


        private readonly FinanceApp.Models.FinanceAppARContext _context;

        public CreateModel(FinanceApp.Models.FinanceAppARContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            PopulateSiteDropDownList(_context, PYSiteSL);
            PopulateManagerDropDownList(_context, PYManagerSL);
            PopulateJobNumDropDownList(_context, PYJobNumSL);

            return Page();
        }
```

and this is the frontend .cshtml

```
//Site
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="py21.Sites" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="py21.Sites" asp-items="Model.PYSiteSL" class="form-control chosen-select"><option disabled selected>-- Select Site --</option></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="py21.Sites" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
//Manager
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="py21.Manager" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="py21.Manager" class="form-control" readonly />
                @*<select asp-for="py21.Manager" asp-items="Model.PYManagerSL" class="form-control chosen-select"><option disabled selected>-- Select Manager --</option></select>*@
                <span asp-validation-for="py21.Manager" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
//JobNum
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="py21.JobNum" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="py21.JobNum" class="form-control" readonly />
                @*<select asp-for="py21.JobNum" asp-items="Model.PYJobNumSL" class="form-control chosen-select"><option disabled selected>-- Select Job Number --</option></select>*@
                <span asp-validation-for="py21.JobNum" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
```

Edited what @StriplingWarrior said, a typo.

Comment: Did you notice that you left `asp-for="py21.Manager"` on your last `<input`?

Comment: Oh my, yea thanks for the spot, I quickly edited it for this question as it was originally the select list without a solution yet so it's a copy-paste. @StriplingWarrior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `.cshtml.cs` page, you could create [a handler method](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/handler-methods) to retrieve data based on the select Site. Then, in the `.cshtml` page, you can attach the DropDownList `onchange` event, in this event, get the DropDownList selected value and use `JQuery.Ajax` to call the Handler method and get the related JobNum and Manager, then, sets the text box value.

More detail information, please refer the following sample:

Create the following models:

```
public class PYViewModel //page view model
{
    public string Sites { get; set; }
    public string Manager { get; set; }
    public string JobNum { get; set; }
}

public class MasterModel //EF entity
{
    [Key]
    public string JobNum { get; set; }
    public string Site { get; set; }
    public string Manager { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{  
    public DbSet<MasterModel> Masters { get; set; }
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

After migration and add the data, the Masters table as below:

[image]

.cshtml.cs page:

```
public class PYPageModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public PYViewModel py21 { get; set; }
    public SelectList PYSiteSL { get; set; }  
    //you could change the applicationdbcontext to yours.
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    public PYPageModel(ApplicationDbContext context)
    { 
        _context = context;
    }
    public void OnGet()
    { 
        //query the master table.
        PYSiteSL = new SelectList(_context.Masters.Distinct().ToList(), nameof(MasterModel.Site), nameof(MasterModel.Site));
    }
    public JsonResult OnGetGetJobNumManager(string selectSite)
    {
        //based on the selected site to filter data.
        return new JsonResult(_context.Masters.Distinct().Where(c=>c.Site == selectSite).Distinct().ToList());
    }
}
```

.cshtml page:

```
@page
@model RazorPageSample.Pages.PYPageModel
<form method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="py21.Sites" class="control-label"></label>
        <select asp-for="py21.Sites" asp-items="Model.PYSiteSL" id="ddlsite" class="form-control chosen-select"><option disabled selected>-- Select Site --</option></select>
        <span asp-validation-for="py21.Sites" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="py21.Manager" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="py21.Manager" class="form-control" readonly />
        @*<select asp-for="py21.Manager" asp-items="Model.PYManagerSL" class="form-control chosen-select"><option disabled selected>-- Select Manager --</option></select>*@
        <span asp-validation-for="py21.Manager" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="py21.JobNum" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="py21.JobNum" class="form-control" readonly />
        @*<select asp-for="py21.JobNum" asp-items="Model.PYJobNumSL" class="form-control chosen-select"><option disabled selected>-- Select Job Number --</option></select>*@
        <span asp-validation-for="py21.JobNum" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</form>
    @section Scripts{
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $("#ddlsite").on("change", function () {
                    var site = $(this).val();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: `?handler=GetJobNumManager&selectSite=${site}`, 
                        type: 'Get', 
                        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                            xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                                $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                        },
                        success: function (result) {
                            var manager = [];
                            var JobNum = [];
                            $.each(result, function (i, item) {
                                manager.push(item.manager);
                                JobNum.push(item.jobNum);
                            }); 
                            $("#py21_Manager").val(manager.join(","));
                            $("#py21_JobNum").val(JobNum.join(","));
                        }, 
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        },
                        failure: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    }
```

The result as below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! Looks like you did it and yours works like a charm. However, I'm not sure where or what I did wrong.

I already have 2 models, py and master, I followed your subsequent step for the .cshtml.cs page but at GetMasters() I have a '...does not contain definition for and no accessible extension method'.

Comment: The `IDataRepository` and the `GetMasters()` method used to set the initial data source (master) for the master, you could change it to your code, query the database via DbContext and get the master.

Comment: In the Client side, use F12 developer tools to add a break point in the DropDownList `change` event, then check whether the `change` event is triggered or not. Then, in the Handler method, you can also set a break point, then debug the application and check whether this method is called or not? If not, check the URL in the JQuery Ajax.

Comment: What if I already have all the data in the db, do I have to manually add it like this `new MasterModel(){ JobNum="T1900003", Site="AIR LIQ", Manager="CLIVE", IsActive=true},
`? I have over hundreds.

Comment: No. If you already have all data in the db, just query the database via the dbContext, then, you can get all masters.

Comment: Hi @FlyingSpiderMonkey, I have modified the code to use DbContext, you could refer to it.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Zhi Lv, I saw it, truly truly appreciate it. Currently I'm just trying to figure out the `change` event. I checked everything and followed your instructions to check in client side. I added all jQuery, checked the id. There was something amiss, probably because of my chosen js for the select box, it added a "_chosen" behind my id="ddlsite", so I changed the one in function to `$("#ddlsite_chosen").on("change", function () {...` but it still doesn't work

Comment: Hi @FlyingSpiderMonkey, try to use F12 developer Console tools to check if there have any error? And, try to use F12 developer Elements tools to check the rendered select element, check the id attribute's value, make sure you are using the same value when use JQuery to find the element. And, the JQuery script should be add after the document is ready: `$(function () { $("#ddlsite_chosen").change(function () {`. Besides, try to use the `$("#ddlsite_chosen").change(function () { ...`. If still not working, can you share the whole JS scripts?

Comment: Check the [chosen.js document](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/), we can see that it use `$("#form_field").chosen().change( … );` to trigger a "change" event on the original form field, you can try to use it.

Comment: There are no errors in the Console, I inspected the dropdown itself, it is indeed title id="ddl_chosen". I have changed it in my JS and tried multiple times, using both `.on("change", function())` and `.change(function())`. I tried including `id="py21_Manager"` and `id="py21_JobNum"` as well in `<input>` but still to no avail.

Comment: Tried `$("#form_field").chosen().change( … );` previously. I thought I was entirely wrong because the event doesn't even show up in the console Event Listener, but the one you did showed `change` Event Listener

Comment: Hi @FlyingSpiderMonkey, Have you ever solved the problem? If not, can create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example to reproduce the problem, and then share it via Github or OneDrive, then we can work together to figure it out.

Comment: Thank you for following up Zhi Lv, you have been amazing help. I removed chosen and it works so the issue is that, I will figure it out on my own if I wish to use Chosen but you have answered the main issue at hand. Truly thank you, have been struggling at this for quite some time.